# Java static and dynamic binding, upcast, overloading mixed together

Tags: java, inheritance, dynamic-binding, static-binding

Let's say that we have the following code

```
class TestEqual{
    public boolean equals(TestEqual other ) {
    System.out.println( "In equals from TestEqual" ); return false;
}

    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        Object t1 = new TestEqual(), t2 = new TestEqual();
        TestEqual t3 = new TestEqual();
        Object o1 = new Object();

        int count = 0;
        System.out.println( count++ );// shows 0
        t1.equals( t2 ) ;
        System.out.println( count++ );// shows 1
        t1.equals( t3 );
        System.out.println( count++ );// shows 2
        t3.equals( o1 );
        System.out.println( count++ );// shows 3
        t3.equals(t3);
        System.out.println( count++ );// shows 4
        t3.equals(t2);
    }
}
```

Basically, in the TestEqual class (that of course, extends Object) we have a method that is overloading the equals method from Object.

Also, we have some variables: Object t1, t2 instanced as TestEqual, TestEqual t3 instanced as TestEqual and an Object o1 instanced as an Object.

If we run the program, this will be the output.

```
0
1
2
3
In equals from TestEqual
4
```

This example seems a bit more complicated than the usual Car c = new Vehicle(); c.drive(); because the object from where we call the method is instanced different from its type, and also the parameter of the method is instanced different than its type.

I would like to check if I understood correctly what happens when we call each method, step-by-step regarding binding.

```
 show 0
 t1.equals(t2)
 show 1
```

t1 is considered as a TestEqual object. The method equals is overloaded, so the binding is static, this means that we will pass t2 as an Object, so it will call the equals method inherited from the Object superclass, so it will not show any text.

```
 show 1
 t1.equals(t3)
 show 2
```

This seems a bit weird. I would have expected to show "In equals from TestEqual", because t3 is a TestEqual object, so the equals from t1 should be called. My explanation here would be that t1 is static bound and considered as an Object, so the method equals inherited from the Object class is called, the parameter TestEqual t3 being upcast to Object.
But wouldn't this mean that the previous explanation from t1.equals(t2) is wrong?

```
show 2
t3.equals(o1);
show 3
```

t3 is a TestEqual object, the parameter o1 is an Object, so the equals method inherited from Object is called, thus nothing is printed.

```
show 3
t3.equals(t3)
show 4
```

t3 is a TestEqual object, the parameter is a TestEqual object, so the overloaded method from TestEqual will be called, printing "In equals from TestEqual".

```
show 4
t3.equals(t2)
```

t3 is a TestEqual object, the parameter is an Object due to static binding (overloaded method), so the equal method inherited from Object is called, printing nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This seems a bit weird. I would have expected to show "In equals from
>   TestEqual", because t3 is a TestEqual object, so the equals from t1
>   should be called. My explanation here would be that t1 is static bound
>   and considered as an Object, so the method equals inherited from the
>   Object class is called, the parameter TestEqual t3 being upcast to Object. But wouldn't this mean that the previous explanation from t1.equals(t2) is wrong?

To call a method in the context of overloading, most specific method invocation is happened and it is determined while compile time. The rule to chose the most specific method is defined in [java language specification 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5): with other discussion, a mentioned statement is:

> A method m1 is strictly more specific than another method m2 if and
>   only if m1 is more specific than m2 and m2 is not more specific than
>   m1.

To explain your context, however lets declare two simple Super class and sup class:

```
class SuperA
{
    public void test(SuperA a)
    {
        System.out.println("super class's test() is called");
    }
}

class SubB extends SuperA
{

    public void test(SubB subB)
    {
        System.out.println("subclass's test() is called");


    }    
}
```

Now, If we create two instance this way:

```
SuperA obj = new SubB();
SubB obj2 = new SubB();
obj.test(obj2);
```

You will see that super class's `test()` is called, because it is determined  as more specific  at compile time and compiler sees that `obj` is an instance of type `SuperA`. Now cast the `obj` to `SuubB` and invoke `test(obj2)`:

```
((SubB)obj).test(obj2); // cast to SubB
```

And it print: `"subclass's test() is called"` implying that it calls the `test(obj)` method of `SubB` because this time compiler knows that `obj` has the type of `SubB` and most specific resolution for invoking `test`.

However, Now lets declare two instance this way:

```
   SuperA obj = new SubB();
   SuperA obj2 = new SubB();
   obj.test(obj2); // invokes super class's test method
   ((SubB)obj).test(obj2);// invokes super class's test method
   ((SubB)obj).test((SubB)obj2); // invoke sub class's test method
```

In this series of invocation, the first two statement will invoke super class `SuperA`'s test method because these invocation is more specific. To explain the second case however:

```
((SubB)obj).test(obj2);// invokes super class's test method
```

This time compiler knows that `obj` has the type of `SubB` but it still sees that `obj2` has the type of `SperA` which is more specific for `test` method invocation. Hence for second example, in which both `obj` and `obj2` was declared with type `SuperA`: we will need both of them to cast to `SubB` to invoke `SubB`'S `test` method.

As `Object` is the super class of all the class in java, you should understand by now, however the `equal` method invocation system of your context. To avoid this kind of invocation pitfalls, you will see that all the implemented `equal` method in classes of java is actually *override* of  `equal` method `Object` class and made use of `instanceof` checking. For example, the equal method implementation of `Integer` class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Integer) { //<<<---- instance of checking
            return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The method [Object.equals(Object obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) takes another `Object` instance as a parameter.
If you define your `TestEqual` as :

```
class TestEqual{
    @override
    public boolean equals(Object other ) {
        System.out.println( "In equals from TestEqual" ); return false;
    }
}
```

It will work as you expect.

Comment: Yes it would work as expected because we override the method from Object.
But what I've wanted to hear was if I understood correctly what happens when we call each method, step-by-step regarding binding. In other words, are my explanations for each call, correct?

Comment: I don't think this one answered Robert's question at all. We know the correct way but he expected an explanation.